# How to create a line of wool sorted by color?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've been trying to figure out a way to create the best possible arrangement of wool colors, so far with no luck.

Does anybody know a reference or an already made list of colors I could use?

This is the closest I could get, but it feels off:

[image: minecraft wool colors]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is what I came up with:

[image]

And it looks pretty correct to me. Colors from left to right: white, light gray, gray, black, brown, red, orange, yellow, lime, green, cyan, light blue, blue, purple, magenta, pink

Here they are in a line (since you're limited to a 9-wide inventory space):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

maybe white, pink, magenta, purple, blue, light blue, cyan, green, lime, yellow, orange, red, brown, black, grey, light grey. so basically what the guy before me had but flipped until white